# Code Challenge: Convert var_dump of array to json

Tags: php, regex, arrays, json, var-dump

I have never really thought about this until today, but after searching the web I didn't really find anything. Maybe I wasn't wording it right in the search.

Given a nested array where var_dumped

```
<pre>array(3) { 'id' =>  string(19) "as-agent-to-shipper" 'name' => string(19) "as-agent-to-shipper" 'children' => array(1) {
[0] =>
array(3) {
  'id' =>
  string(28) "agility-logistics-s-a-de-c-v"
  'name' =>
  string(30) "AGILITY LOGISTICS S.A. DE C.V."
  'data' =>
  array(2) {
    'band' =>
    string(22) "-AS AGENT TO SHIPPER -"
    'relation' =>
    string(13) "Buyer of band"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The challenge is this: What is the best optimized method for converting a var_dumped array to json?
Is it just a matter of regex? Or is there some other way? I am looking for creativity.

Comment: Just print_r instead of vardump and show the result

Comment: Can we see your attempt first? I guess it would have to be recursive.

Comment: can't [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) or **[json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)** help you instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It most likely  is impossible to parse this structure using RegEx.

It would be possible to write a specialized parser for it, but given that PHP makes [no promises on its format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), it is a very bad idea to do so. In a minor PHP version update the format could change and the parser would stop working.

Even more, `var_dump` is lossy, that is there are cases when you can not recover the state of an object just by its representation. The simplest example would be resources. `var_dump`ing an open file returns `resource(5) of type (stream)`, which is completely not enough to do anything useful with it.

All in all, it just sounds like a bad idea, and whatever problem would be solved by it, should be solved differently.